# How to end my players animation in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So, i have this animation called push. I want it to play when the player collides with the box i added. I wrote some codes and it works, push animation is starting when the player touches the box but it won't stop. I want the animation to stop whenever player stops touching the box. How i can make this possible? Here are my codes i wrote for this part:
`

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "box")
        {
            anim.SetBool("Push", true);
        }

    }
```

`

[image: This how the Animator panel looks like]

[image: this is the player and the box]

[image: This is how the inspector box panel looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OnCollisionExit to detect when collision stops.
Example:

```
OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D,other)
{
     if(other.gameObject.tag == "box")
     {
          anim.SetBool("Push",false);
          // or anim.Play("IdleAnimationName");
     }
}
```

The specified tag in On Collision Exit will be used to determine when the player stops colliding with that specific tag.